# PHP Session Variable not staying Constant

Tags: php, session

I have an issue with using `$_Session[]`, I am trying to set a constant variable which should be active across all my pages.

It becomes active when someone successfully logs in, on login.php ( `$logged_in` gets set to `1` )

Here is the code for **action.php:**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<?php
    if($logged_in==1) {
        $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $username;
    }
?>
<head>
```

action.php is where all of the form processes are done, so `$logged_in` gets set in action.php.

Then I attempt to call `$_SESSION['logged_user']` in **index.php:**

```
(link to code) http://pastebin.com/8BA3csUZ
```

But as you can see by looking at the code: I attempt to call it `<?php echo $_SESSION['logged_in']; ?>` but nothing happens, how come?

**edit:
Login code:**

```
if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] === "login") {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password_input = $_POST['password'];
$password = md5($password_input);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if($password == $row['password']) {
echo "successful login";
$logged_in = 1;
}
else { echo "unsuccessful login";}
}
}
```

...and yes I am aware of md5 not really doing much ;)

Comment: What is `$logged_in`?

Comment: in that top example, `$logged_in` is not defined anywhere. Show us your login.php code (which should be setting `$_SESSION['logged_in']` and you should be using that to check)

Comment: Hi, do you get any php errors, warnings or notices in your php error log ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($_GET['do']) && $_GET['do'] === "login") {
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password_input = $_POST['password'];
$password = md5($password_input);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
if($password == $row['password']) {
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 1;
echo "successful login";
}
else { echo "unsuccessful login";}
}
}
```

Comment: doesn't session_start() have to before the head etc..?

Comment: sure, you can put it on the top of your page, your mistake was that you didn't define the logged in as a session variable...

Comment: session_start() has to be before content is sent to the client, not necessarily at the start, where most people put it.  Also, lookup SQL Injection ... your mysqli_query call is vulnerable.